# TestCase display name in NUnit when using Arrays or Generics

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, nunit, testcase

I am trying to use `TestCaseSource` in NUnit to run multiple tests with one of parameters being an array

```
    private static readonly object[] ReturnChopCases =
    {
        new TestCaseData(3, new List<int> {}).Returns(-1),
        new TestCaseData(3, new List<int> {1}).Returns(1),
        new TestCaseData(1, new List<int> {1,2}).Returns(1),
    };

    [TestCaseSource("ReturnChopCases")]
    public int test_chop(int SearchNumber, int[] SearchArray)
    {
        return Chopper.Chop(3, SearchArray);
    }
```

The problem is the name displayed in the test runner (I'm using the NUnit Test Adapter) is pretty useless, they all show as `test_chop(0,System.Int32[])` or if using a `List` then `` test_chop(0,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]) ``.

How do I retain a fairly readable test and give a useful test name to the test in the test runner? I've tried a few things but I still get the name mentioned above.

Comment: You can just name the tests explicitly if you tack on `.SetName("your name")`.  You may be looking for something more automatic though.

Comment: Yes I was actually surprised it didn't do something better with arrays in particular. `.SetName("")` looks like the best option or I could write a method to pass in a name for these tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SetName` function to name the Test

```
new TestCaseData(3, new List<int> {}).Returns(-1).SetName("test_chop_List<int>"),
```

Comment: Although I wish there was a better solution this looks like it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I went with, first I created a class for my custom test case

```
public class CustomTestCase
{
    public CustomTestCase(int SearchNumber, List<int> List, int Result)
    {
        searchNumber = SearchNumber;
        list = List;
        result = Result;
    }
    private int searchNumber;
    private List<int> list;
    private int result;

    public string TestName()
    {
        return string.Format("TestChop({0},{{{1}}})", searchNumber, String.Join(",", list));
    }

    public TestCaseData SimpleTest()
    {
        return new TestCaseData(searchNumber, list).Returns(result).SetName(this.TestName());
    }
}
```

And then I used that to build the `TestCaseSource`

```
private static IEnumerable ReturnChopCases()
{
    List<int> emptyList = new List<int> { };
    yield return new CustomTestCase(3,emptyList,-1).SimpleTest();

    List<int> singleItemList = new List<int> { 1 };
    yield return new CustomTestCase(3, singleItemList, 1).SimpleTest();
    yield return new CustomTestCase(3, singleItemList, 1).SimpleTest();
}
```

The Test is the same.

I still think NUnit should generate more useful names but I found this the easiest way to deal with my problem and if I want to deal with exceptions I could just create another method to handle those.

NB: Don't forget to include `using System.Collections;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;`.